# Attempting to use a 'for' loop to build an Array

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to build an array whose entries are the letters of any given word. I though I had written a clever bit of code, but it doesn't work in the slightest! And feedback or help would be greatly appreciated:

```
var inputWord = prompt("PALINDROME CHECKER:");
var numberOfLetters = inputWord.length;

var letters = [];
for(i=0; i++; i<numberOfLetters){
  letters[i] = inputWord.substring(i,i+1);
};
```

Thanks,
CPR

Comment: Tip: `"abcdef".split("");`.

Comment: You could just use split(). var letters = inputWord.split('') though you may then need to remove spaces and other characters. – RickTakes just now   edit

Comment: A string can be accessed as an array.  "hello"[0] would give you the letter "h"

Answer (score 2):

If you want an array with the letters of a string, just split the string with no pattern:

```
var string = "My string is this";
var array = string.split("");
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is wrong. Try:

```
var inputWord = prompt("PALINDROME CHECKER:");
var numberOfLetters = inputWord.length;

var letters = [];
for(i=0; i<numberOfLetters; i++){
  letters[i] = inputWord.substring(i,i+1);
};
```

The order of the `for` loop parameters should be iterator, then condition, then action - basically, "for my variable `i`, if `i` is less than the number of letters, then increment `i`"